# How to create uppercase in pure HTML

Tags: html

I am aware about this

```
<p class="uppercase">This is some text.</p>
```

But I'd not want a paragraph. Is there any other way to create uppercase in HTML?

Comment: If you do not want a paragraph, what *do* you want?

Comment: I think this is just an unresearched question where he wants his text to be inline, therefore not wanting to use the p tag.

Comment: Correct. Pure HTML. Inline.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Do you have to use strict HTML? If you can use the style attribute, you can write:

```
<span style="text-transform:uppercase">This is some text.</span>
```

Span elements are inline just like text outside of any element.

Answer (score 3):

CSS

```
p.uppercase {
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

HTML

```
<p class="uppercase">This is some text.</p>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can make any text on HTML text uppercase by using CSS. As you told that you do not want a paragraph then do as described below.

Step 1: wrap the words or lines you want to be on uppercase inside  tag. Ex. `<span> This line will be in uppercase </span>`.

Step2: Ass css on to the span tag as shown here `<span style="text-transform:uppercase;"> This line will be in uppercase </span>`. That's it.Now reload the HTML and you will see the line is on uppercase.

You can learn more about this on here for free of cost  https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_text-transform.asp